# Rails: Suppress output in view for some code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose my array looks like this:

```
People => [
  {
    ID => /org/div/emp/123,
    Person => Jack,
    Age => 25
  },
  {
    ID => /org/div/emp/124,
    Person => Frank,
    Age => 45
  },
  {
    ID => /org/div/emp/125,
    Person => Molly,
    Age => 30
  }
]
```

I'm passing this array to my view using the @People variable.

My view is simple right now:

```
<h1>People</h1>
  <% @People.each do |person| %>
    <%= uri = person[ID].split("/") %>
    <p>
    Person: <%= person[Person] %> <br/>
    Age: <%= person[Age] %> <br/>
    ID: <%= uri[4] %>
    <br/>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

The problem is that, due to how views work, whenever I split person[ID] it is displayed as an array:

```
People

  ["org", "div", "emp", "123"]

  Person: Jack
  Age: 25
  ID: 123

  ["org", "div", "emp", "124"]

  Person: Frank
  Age: 45
  ID: 124

  ["org", "div", "emp", "125"]

  Person: Molly
  Age: 30
  ID: 125
```

How do I go about getting the ID from the URI without the array being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<%= uri = person[ID].split("/") %>` use `<%- uri = person[ID].split("/") %>` instead.